# The official documentation for creating a NextJS app with Typescript doesn't seem to work

Tags: typescript, npm, next.js

I've been trying to use Typescript for my NextJS projects for a moment... I thought getting started with Typescript would be the hardest, but no: its installation is even more complicated.

I followed what's said on the [official documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/typescript) (to create a new project).

Here is what i've done exactly:

```
npx create-next-app --ts
cd test-nextts
npm run dev
```

Here is the error I'm getting on `npm run dev`:

```
> test-nextts@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
It looks like you're trying to use TypeScript but do not have the required package(s) installed.

Please install @types/react by running:

        npm install --save-dev @types/react

If you are not trying to use TypeScript, please remove the tsconfig.json file from your package root (and any TypeScript files in your pages directory).
```

It's saying that I don't have the "required package(s) installed", whereas I do. Here is the `package.json` automatically generated after `npx create-next-app --ts`:

```json
{
  "name": "test-nextts",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "12.1.4",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "17.0.23",
    "@types/react": "18.0.2", // <--- HERE IT IS
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "eslint": "8.13.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.1.4",
    "typescript": "4.6.3"
  }
}
```

It asks me to run `npm install --save-dev @types/react` (even though I should not have to do it). The process happens normally:

```
up to date, audited 228 packages in 714ms

63 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Therefore, I try another `npm run dev`, and here is the problem: it prints the exact same error over and over again! Why?

I have the same error if I try to modify an existing Javascript project.

Please, help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug, the latest version of `create-next-app` doesn't work with React 18

Here is the official issue: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/36085

Subscribe to follow it

Comment: Ok, thank you. The issue was posted 4 hours ago only. The proposed workaround worked for me: `npm i --save-dev @types/react@18.0.1`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider to update Next.js to 12 or higher. Also, the React version should be latest. There is a brief documentation about upgrading:

https://nextjs.org/docs/upgrading#upgrade-nextjs-version-to-12